# How to open any program from the terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, shortcut

Often in the terminal I want to open a specific file (since I've already browsed to the right directory).

A few programs I have come with their own links ready, like `subl index.html` will open Sublime Text editor. Also I am aware of the `open foo` which will call the file to be opened in the default program associated with it.

How can I setup a more general way of opening a file from the terminal with a specific program, either by defining a per-program helper/shortcut, or better even, in a generic way?

Comment: Is `open -a APP_NAME FILE` OK?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks! I suggested to edit the linked question to be titled more general, since the answer there answers my problem.

Comment: Thanks to your question above there is no need to rephrase the existing question. The "duplicate" link will lead anybody to the answers either way.